# Why is Datetime's `.timestamp()` method returning `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, epoch

I make use of the `.timestamp()` function twice in my code, to convert datetime objects into epoch time. The first call to `.timestamp()` looks like this:

```
import datetime    
origin_epoch = origin.timestamp()
```

the contents of the variables `origin` and `origin_epoch` are:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Code's debugger for variables.]

Meanwhile, if I try to call the same method elsewhere in my code

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 19, 6, 28).timestamp())
```

Then I get the following error: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` Why is this?

**edit:** this error occurred on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The year 1900 was before the beginning of [the UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which was in 1970, so the number of seconds returned by `timestamp` must be negative. To be precise, [*should* be negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708622/how-to-represent-dates-before-epoch-as-a-unix-timestamp), but apparently, not in your case. Looks like your OS just treats dates before the beginning of the UNIX epoch as errors.

This works fine for me on macOS, though:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 19, 6, 28).timestamp()
-2208929029.0
```

Comment: Wow, I never would have guessed this. Thanks so much! It's funny because, if you don't specify a year, the default year in the datetime module is 1900. So on windows, whenever you run `timestamp()` on a datetime object with the default year, the program will crash with this "Errno 22"

Comment: @David, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54470408/4354477) may also be helpful

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted. Your answer does not point into any direction how to solve the issue on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue29097) which has been supposedly fixed, but I haven't checked. On my Windows (Windows 10, GMT+2) any date before 1970-01-02 02:00:00 or beyond 3001-01-19 07:59:59 will give an `OSError` when `timestamp()` is called.

However, this does not happen to offset-aware datetime, instead, a call to `timestamp()` gets computed as (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)):

```
(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()
```

So if you work with offset-naive datetimes, you can simply use:

```
(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug. This code will work on Windows as well:

```
import datetime
year = 1952
print((datetime.date(year, 1, 1) - datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())
```

If you want to be precise, make sure the year 2023 yields the same value as this code:

```
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1).timestamp()
```

Depending on your timezone add or subtract 3600 times the number of hours that your timezone differs.

Answer (score -1):

I replaced the year value with 2000 and now it works fine.

```
time_sec = datetime.strptime("00:00:13.345", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(time_sec.replace(year=2000).timestamp())
```