# An error occurs in Windows - OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument - datetime

Tags: windows, datetime, timestamp, python-3.9

An error occurs in Windows:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

while everything works as it should in Linux

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
a.timestamp() # - an error occurs here
```

How can I fix this in Windows?

Comment: expected output - 0.0

Comment: No, because it doesn't mention fromtimestamp. The problem in timestamp arises from the datetime object that was created with fromtimestamp(0)

Comment: apologies for my initial comment, which I think was misleading. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65564765/10197418) basically says "it's a Windows thing" and "doesn't happen with aware datetime" (which I can reproduce). But: it gives no clue as to *why* this happens on Windows. Anyhow, my takeaway would be: work with aware datetime whenever you can (preferably UTC)