# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when using datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I tested the following code :

```
date_string = "16:30"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%H:%M")
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(date)
print(timestamp)
```

But I got the error :

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

[image]

What should I do to get the timestamp of the time?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Please add the full traceback.

Comment: Does your code include *from datetime import datetime* ? If it does, I can't reproduce this on macOS

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: related: [Why is Datetime's .timestamp() method returning OSError: Errno 22 Invalid argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59199985/10197418), [An error occurs in Windows - OSError: Errno 22 Invalid argument - datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67898530/10197418)

Answer (score 5):

Your code works if you make the datetime object aware, i.e. set a time zone:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

date_string = "16:30"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%H:%M").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

print(date)
# 1900-01-01 16:30:00+00:00

print(date.timestamp())
# -2208929400.0
```

(Tested on Windows 10, Python 3.9.12)

A bit of background, from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> datetime.timestamp() ...     Naive datetime instances are assumed to
> represent local time and this method relies on the platform C mktime()
> function to perform the conversion.

So, if you call the `.timestamp()` method on a naive datetime object, *local time* (i.e. the UTC offset at given date/time) must be determined. If your platform's `mktime` doesn't support this for a given Unix time, you see `OSError: [Errno 22]`. In contrast, if you set the time zone (i.e. specify the UTC offset), that call to mktime is not necessary and the error is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `timestamp()` doesn't have arguments (and it is exactly what the stack trace is telling you: `Invalid argument`.

I think you want `date.timestamp()`, so a method from your `date` variable (`date` is a `datetime.datetime` instance, and not the class `datetime.date`).

But I think you are importing datetime as `from datetime import datetime`. Do not do it. it will just confuse you and your editor, so you may get invalid suggestions from your IDE. And also do not use variable name `date` if you use `datetime`, but also in general, never use so generic variable names. It just confuse everything. Prefer a better variable name, e.g. a `this_date` or `my_date` (so nobody will confuse with datetime.date, especially if in future you need that clas). But better to set a better name.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with the code. **Datetime Module** takes the default year *(1900-01-01)*.

Time Module Supports from 1970-01-01 onwards. If you run below you got to know that.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime(0)))
```

In your code you didn't mention the date. so it is taking default date *(1900-01-01)*. For more info [Click Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)