# why datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0).timestamp() should raise exception (python>=3.7)

Tags: python, datetime, oserror

is there a logical reason or it's a bug that

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0).timestamp()
```

raises OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument?

I would expect as result 0.0 as I'm passing from timestamp 0 to datetime and again back to timestamp

I'm on Win10 (tested with 3.7, 3.11)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460238/11305029

Comment: I only tried "datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)" and it worked for me . It gives me the Unix Timestamp back. What would you like to archive?

Comment: This is a platform-specific problem. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71680355/10197418

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I don't think the dupe you linked is appropriate (outdated Python version, IMHO no satisfying/accepted solution). There are more specific ones like the one I linked in the comment above, or also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59199985/10197418 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/67898530/10197418