# how to convert datetime-like string into milliseconds

Tags: python, string, datetime, timedelta

I have a user-defined function (`return_times`) that takes json file and returns two datetime-like strings.

```
time_1, time_2= return_times("file.json")
print(time_1, time_2) # outputs: 00:00:11.352 00:01:51.936
```

By datetime-like string I mean `00:00:11.352` which suits `'%H:%M:%S.%f'` formatting. However, when I try to convert them into milliseconds, I get negative values.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_obj_1 = datetime.strptime(time_1, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
start_ms = dt_obj_1.timestamp() * 1000

dt_obj_2 = datetime.strptime(time_2, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
end_ms = dt_obj_2.timestamp() * 1000

print(start_ms, end_ms ) # outputs: -2209019260648.0 -2209019160064.0
```

If I success I would like to trim a video with the following command:

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
ffmpeg_extract_subclip("long_video.mp4", start_ms, end_ms, targetname="video_trimmed.mp4"), so just delete ` * 1000` part.
```

**Note** that `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` requires its `t1` and `t2` parameters to be in seconds, not in milliseconds as I initially thought.

Because of those negative integers I am not able to successfully run the trimming process.
I searched the web that mainly discusses several formats for the year, month and day, but not `'%H:%M:%S.%f'`.

What may I be overlooking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59200108/2681662

Comment: This looks more like a time only, not date and time. Or do you mean timedelta, i.e. a duration?

Comment: if you happen to use `pandas`: `pd.to_timedelta("00:00:11.352").total_seconds()*1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What may I be overlooking?*

[`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) docs

> The default values used to fill in any missing data when more accurate
> values cannot be inferred are `(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1)`.

whilst start of epoch is 1970. You might get what you want by computing delta between what you parsed and default strptime as follows:

```
import datetime
time1 = "00:00:11.352"
delta = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, "%H:%M:%S.%f") - datetime.datetime.strptime("", "")
time_s = delta.total_seconds()
print(time_s)
```

output

```
11.352
```

Comment: this answered my main question which solves the value returning a value in milliseconds. Do note that, `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` requires `t1` and `t2` to be in seconds in milliseconds (as I initially thought). @Daweo, edit your answer so that is time_ms in seconds not ms. I will do the same with my question.

Comment: @bit_scientist I edited my answer, note that whilst `ffpmeg_extract_subclip` require float, if you use `ffmpeg` directly (from command line) you might use `00:00:11.352` as-is, see for example following tutorial https://ottverse.com/trim-cut-video-using-start-endtime-reencoding-ffmpeg/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the year date (year, month, day) to `datetime`, else this will default to 1 January 1900.

What you do is this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
s = "00:00:11.352" 
f = '%H:%M:%S.%f'
datetime.strptime(s, f) # datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 11, 352000)
```

One way to do this is to append the date-string to the time-string you receive from `return_times`

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/59200108/2681662

> The year 1900 was before the beginning of [the UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which
> was in 1970, so the number of seconds returned by timestamp must be
> negative.

### What to do?

It's better to use a `time` object instead of a `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import time

time_1 = "00:00:11.352"
hours, minutes, seconds = time_1.split(":")

print(time(hour=int(hours), minute=int(minutes), second=int(float(seconds)),
           microsecond=int(float(seconds) % 1 * 1000000)))
```

Comment: since the OP wants total (milli)seconds, I don't think you need a `time` object at all. Also, if you map the "seconds" part to a float, fractional seconds are already included.

Comment: I actually tried to map the seconds to `float`. However the `time` object expect the value as an `int`. `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`

Comment: The reason I thought a `time` object would be better is, in an extreme condition the `datetime` delta object may have leap second.

Comment: the point is, the input represents a duration, not a time of day. So time or datetime are inappropriate data structures in my opinion. Concerning leap seconds, see also [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail), technical note #4.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the time string into hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds and with some simple math calculations, you get the whole time in miliseconds

Comment: Actually this is a good approach (e.g. `sum(a*b for a, b in zip(map(float, "00:00:11.352".split(':')), (3600, 60, 1)))`. However, you should add an example to make this a helpful answer. Otherwise, this should be a comment.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a newbie in stackoverflow and dont have reputation needed to add comment. thanks for the advice

Comment: commenting takes 40 rep I think, so it shouldn't take you too long to get there. you can also edit your answer to improve it.