# How to convert a date formatted string before 1970 into a timestamp in windows

Tags: python, windows, datetime

I have been trying to convert a formatted string like
`"1900-01-01"` into a timestamp

```
datetime.strptime('1900-01-01','%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
```

this works fine in linux/mac but in windows I got an error
`OSError [Errno22] invalid argument` I understand that windows don't support datetime before 1970

Would you please suggest a workround for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470408/workaround-for-datetime-timestamp-on-windows-for-dates-preceeding-1970-01-01

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workaround for datetime timestamp() on windows for dates preceeding 1970-01-01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470408/workaround-for-datetime-timestamp-on-windows-for-dates-preceeding-1970-01-01)

Comment: i think the questions are related, but the answer didn't work for me

Comment: the linked question uses gregorian epoch, 1582-Oct-15. you need to adjust that to UNIX time epoch.

Comment: i see, thats why I got confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the total_seconds from a `timedelta`, which you obtain by subtracting the epoch:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = (datetime.strptime('1900-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()

# ts
# -2208988800.0
```

Comment: its a far better solution than mine :) I guess i need to get a windows vm

Answer (score 1):

## Here is a possible way using regex and relativedelta

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime

regex = re.match('(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})','1900-01-01')
year, month, date = regex.groups()
year, month, date = int(year), int(month), int(date)
(datetime(year, month, date)-datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

This will give you `-2208988800.0` which is the correct timestamp

Comment: Did you test this on Windows? Since you call `dt.timestamp()`, this won't work either I think. Plus adding regex and dateutil's relativedelta into the game just complicates things. Better stick to the dupe you linked ;-)

Comment: yeah it doesnt work on windows 10, I dont know about other versions but I guess if you call timestamp then subtract the relativedelta , that might work.

Comment: Im surprised the datetime developer didnt implement the workaround by default for windows... maybe they think windows users are second class citizen :( discrimination

Comment: i have requested an edit. This is actually useful for weirdo date string formats that are not supported by the datetime package.

Comment: ok i see, sorry I didn't test out with windows because my workplace stopped using it. and yes I think for them windows is a second class citizen because i imagine most of them use macs. but you can suggest edits in github. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py